# Codable/Decodable should decode Array with Strings

Tags: swift, swift4, codable, decodable

Why is the names Array not decoding?

Prepared for Playground, Simple paste this into your playground

```
import Foundation

struct Country : Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case names
    }

    var names : [String]?
}

extension Country {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        names = try values.decode([String]?.self, forKey: .names)!
    }
}

let json = """
 [{
    "names":
      [
       "Andorre",
       "Andorra",
       "アンドラ"
      ]
 },{
    "names":
      [
       "United Arab Emirates",
       "Vereinigte Arabische Emirate",
       "Émirats Arabes Unis",
       "Emiratos Árabes Unidos",
       "アラブ首長国連邦",
       "Verenigde Arabische Emiraten"
      ]
  }]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let countries = try decoder.decode([Country].self, from: json)
    countries.forEach { print($0) }
} catch {
    print("error")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `names` as an *optional* property of `Country`.
If your intention is that this key may not be present in the JSON
then use `decodeIfPresent`:

```
extension Country {
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        names = try values.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .names)
    }
}
```

This method returns `nil` if the container does not have a value associated with key, or if the value is null.

But actually you can just omit your custom `init(from decoder: Decoder)`
implementation (and the `enum CodingKeys`), because that is the default behaviour and will
be synthesized automatically.

*Remark:* An implicit variable `error` is defined in any `catch` clause,
so

```
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

can be more informative than just a `print("error")` (although not
in this particular case).

Comment: Cool this works! But how to solve that for an `Dictionary<String,String>`. I tried it with `translations = try values.decodeIfPresent(Dictionary<String,String>.self, forKey: .translations)
` but this raises `The operation couldn’t be completed. (Swift.DecodingError error 1.)`. Do you have for this a solution too?

Comment: @Jan: As far as I know (but I am not 100% sure) you cannot decode an *arbitrary* dictionary from JSON. Of course if the keys are fixed then you can define a type with those keys as properties: `struct Translations: Decodable { var en: String?; var de: String?; ... }`

Comment: I got it working with Dicts: `var translations : [String:String?]?
` and `translations = try values.decodeIfPresent([String:String?].self, forKey: .translations)`