# JSON catch error when loading the data with Swift 4

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, swift4

My app was working perfectly in the past 3 weeks then today i got an catch error when i build my app

Api : https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/

This is my code

I create this class in the same ViewController.swift file :

```
struct Coin: Codable {
   let symbol : String
   let price_usd : String
   let percent_change_24h : String }
```

And this in my View controller class :

```
var coins = [Coin]()

var sympolsCoin = [String]()
var priceUSDcoin = [String]()
var lastDayChange = [String]()




func getCoinData() {
    let jsonURL = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"
    let url = URL(string: jsonURL)


    if reachability.connection == .none {
        print("No Internet")

        let noConnection = UIAlertController(title: "Error!", message: "Could not load data, Please check your internet connection and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)

        noConnection.addAction(dismiss)
        present(noConnection, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }else{

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in

        do {
            self.coins = try JSONDecoder().decode([Coin].self, from: data!)

            for info in self.coins {
                self.sympolsCoin.append(info.symbol)
                self.priceUSDcoin.append(info.price_usd)
                self.lastDayChange.append(info.percent_change_24h)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.coinTableView.reloadData()
                }
                //self.coinTableView.reloadData()
                print("JSON DATA HERE : \(self.sympolsCoin)")

            }

        }catch {
            print("Error is : \(error)")
        }
        }.resume()
}
}
```

And this is my tableview :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BitcoinTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BitcoinTableViewCell

    let lineNumbers = Array(1...200)

    let priceFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    priceFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 4
    priceFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
    priceFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal

    let priceUSD = priceUSDcoin.flatMap{ priceString->String? in
        guard let price = Double(priceString) else {return nil}
        return priceFormatter.string(for: price)
    }

    cell.lineNumberLable.text =  " \(lineNumbers[indexPath.row]) -"
    cell.coinNameLable.text = " \(sympolsCoin[indexPath.row])"
    cell.priceLable.text = "$" + priceUSD[indexPath.row]
    cell.lastDayChange.text = lastDayChange[indexPath.row] + "%"

    return cell

}
```

The error comes from the `catch` and print this error to the consol :

Error is : 
valueNotFound(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [Foundation.(_JSONKey in _12768CA107A31EF2DCE034FD75B541C9)(stringValue: "Index 22", intValue: Optional(22)), Bitcoin_tracker.Coin.(CodingKeys in _498D704279C37C1773C9142E11B45D14).percent_change_24h], debugDescription: "Expected String value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Please help me i'm new in swift and JSON

Comment: The value for `percent_change_24h ` of `ardor` is `null`: `"percent_change_24h": null,`, that's something new that you didn't manage before. That's what is causing your crash because you don't manage it. Also, having `var sympolsCoin = [String](); var priceUSDcoin = [String](); var lastDayChange = [String]()` while you already have `var coins = [Coin]()` that's seems a bad idea for your datasource of your `UITableView`. Keep only `var coins = [Coin]()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codable/Decodable should decode Array with Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005742/codable-decodable-should-decode-array-with-strings)