# Trying to parse json, can't seem to parse arrays inside of an array

Tags: json, swift

I've been trying to parse a part of this JSON file: https://opendata.brussels.be/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=traffic-volume&rows=3&facet=level_of_service

I wanna get records->fields->geo_shape->coordinates but I can't seem to print these arrays inside of the "coordinates" array.. I thought it might be because the arrays inside of the coordinates do not have names, so I don't know how to make a variable for them. Got this code currently:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation


struct Geoshape : Codable {
    let coordinates: Array<...>
}
struct Field : Codable {
    let geo_shape: Geoshape
    let level_of_service: String
}
struct Record: Codable {
    let fields: Field
}

struct Traffic: Codable{
    let records: Array<Record>
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func clickRefresh(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://opendata.brussels.be/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=traffic-volume&rows=3&facet=level_of_service") else { return }
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }
         if let data = data {


            let traffic = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Traffic.self, from: data)
            print(traffic)

            }

        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Clearly the Array<...> needs to be changed but I don't know to what. I've tried making an extra struct with just 1 variable (which is another array of the type Double: Double) but that does not seem to work. I was able to print everything just fine up to the point I tried to go into the coordinates array.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005742/codable-decodable-should-decode-array-with-strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
let coordinates: Array<...>
```

with

```
let coordinates:[[Double]]
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all your file in [Resource](https://opendata.brussels.be/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=traffic-volume&rows=3&facet=level_of_service) contains a JSON which contains an array or `Collection` (typically in Swift).

One important thing: If you fail to decode an object in json you get null from all stored properties.
fail occurs when your Coding Keys does not match keys in json or type you are casting is diffrent.

In your code you fail to cast `coordinates` to its type.  coordinates is a collection of collections of `Double`.

```
var coordinates: [[Double]]
```

If you want to fetch data into your models, you should conforms them to `Decodable` protocol which means that,`JSON` attributes can decode itself.

Based on **Apple developer** [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable):

> Decodable is a type that can decode itself from an external representation.

also Codable protocol refers to Decodable and Encodable protocols. but current purpose is Decoding data.

```
typealias Codable = Decodable & Encodable
```

Your code should look like:

### Swift 5

Prepared for Playground, paste this into your playground

```
import Foundation

struct GeoShape: Decodable {
    var coordinates: [[Double]]
}

struct Field: Decodable {
    var geo_shape: GeoShape
}

struct Record: Decodable {
    var fields: Field
}

struct Traffic: Decodable {
    var records: [Record]
}

guard let url = URL.init(string: "https://opendata.brussels.be/api/records/1.0/search/?dataset=traffic-volume&rows=3&facet=level_of_service")
    else {fatalError()}

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ (data, response, error) in
    if let data = data {
        let traffic = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Traffic.self, from: data)
        print("First coordinate is: ",traffic?.records.first?.fields.geo_shape.coordinates.first)
    }
    }.resume()
```